# Changing the top navigation bar Tabs titles

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, master-page, css, html

I need to change the tile for the top navigation tabs, to do so I search for these tabs inside the following folder:-

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources

Then I search for these tab titles inside the core & core.en-Us files,  I was able to modify the title for the items,files,browse,document,events, calendar. But I can not find the Page tab title under these files. So can anyone advice where I can find the “Page” tab which is displayed under all the sites pages.

using something such as :-

Custom title....

[image]

Comment: @tempac do u have any idea about changing the Page title?

Comment: sorry, i don't.